# pass a collection id's

Tags: oracle, plsql

the below query throws

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small.

the function fws_pivot will return rows in columns with comma seperators.
If i try the query for particular id(sfrstcr_pidm) it works but not for a collection . what am i missing

f i try the query for particular id(sfrstcr_pidm) it works

```
SELECT
    fws_pivot( (ssbsect_subj_code|| '-'|| ssbsect_crse_numb || '-' || ssbsect_seq_numb)) AS std_course
FROM
      sfrstcr,
      ssbsect
WHERE
      sfrstcr_crn = ssbsect_crn
  AND sfrstcr_term_code = ssbsect_term_code
  AND sfrstcr_pidm in (select sfbetrm_pidm from sfbetrm where sfbetrm_term_code = '201931')
  AND sfrstcr_term_code = '201931'
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: What does it mean to "return rows in columns with comma separators"?  Is `fws_pivot` a custom aggregate function?  If so, does it return a `varchar2` or a `clob`?  If you've got a custom aggregate function returning a `varchar2`, the result is going to be limited to the maximum SQL `varchar2` size of 4000 bytes (unless you've enabled extended strings in a recent version of Oracle when the limit is 32k).

Comment: @justin even after i changed the size to varchar2(32767).It throws the same error

Comment: Changed what size?  If the guess that this is a custom aggregate function returning a `varchar2` is correct, is the final result less than 32k in length?  Or might it be more than 32k?  If you're concatenating three numbers together with two dashes, I'll guess each row is at least 16 bytes long.  If there are more than 2000 such rows getting concatenated together, you'd need the function to return a `clob` (less if you haven't enabled extended string sizes at the database level).  Depending on the Oracle version, it probably makes more sense to use the built-in `listagg`.

Comment: should i use listagg in place of the function ?

Comment: i am using this inside my function parallel_enable aggregate using gw_string_agg_type

Comment: OK.  So the function is a custom aggregate function.  You could modify your aggregate function to return a `clob` rather than a `varchar2`.

Comment: I increased the size of the output variables in my package and it worked... thank you @justin